# Doctrine partial objects ... is it for performance?

Tags: sql, doctrine

i learnt that in doctrine i can return partial objects. when i just do `print_r()` of the result set returned, they seem to still contain the definations for the fields, except that when i echo them out i get nth. so i guess the definations are there but the values are not. is this for performance? eg. in SQL i shld do `SELECT field1, field2` instead of `SELECT *`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the ability to select just partial objects is, as you say, for performance. However, unless your table is very large, or contains columns with large sized data, I doubt there is a very large effect.

Doctrine can lazy-load the values in columns that are not selected when the object is first created. This can create performance problems, as Doctrine will perform more queries to get the missing data, so try to always make sure the data you use is selected.

Comment: varchar and text fields can easily eat up the performance, hence why SELECTing carefully is import. I'm currently considering using Doctrine, but I'm a little wary of how eager it seems to want to do SELECT *.

Comment: @DavidGraham used it in a number of projects, it always performed adequately for the purposes, but we never stored any particularly large blobs.

Comment: Yes, but consider you have a complex project with several JOINs in your queries. Doctrine is going to grab every single field from all your associations. I'm not storing blobs in the main tables that I work with, but I do have an amount of varchars that (considering the number of rows I want displayed, and the number of users hitting those queries) could be a problem. I just think that there is no silver-bullet with attacking the database as OO. So to add bloat, may not be the best choice. I'm considering it, I just sort of see ORMs as an anti-pattern right now. Trying to warm up to them.

Comment: @DavidGraham They're a tool where any other... They do certain things well, others not so much :) Personally I find they make writing most DB code a lot easier and faster, and at least in Doctrine 2's case, if you find it doesn't perform well in a certain use-case, it's easy to replace with a raw SQL query or such.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand you question completely but in DQL you can do `SELECT *` since the ORM will *always* create a `SELECT field1, field2,....` query out of it.

With regular SQL, you should avoid SELECTing `*` since it will decrease performance.

Answer (score 0):

Partial queries is very useful it you want results that does not include various data such as passwords and such.

I use it for my REST API whereas I don't want to return data such as the User object's password.

Example might be:

```
 SELECT .... JOIN  ... partial user.{user_id, email} ....
```

And then return array with `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY`. Obviously it would not make that much sense if you didn't hydrate your result.

This is useful because you don't want to retrieve the users hashed password for everyone to see ( that is in a REST API where you send data to client applications such as backbone driven, or even iPhone/Android apps ) .